# prove equation has no rational root.

Tags: rational-functions

### Prove

---

> For all $n>1$, equation $\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}+1=0$ has no rational root.

I'm not sure whether there are two questions,for without brace after Sigma.

My thought is to prove it is not reducible on rational field.

Comment: Do you know the rational roots test?

Comment: @Goos Do you mean the Einsenstain test? or other about r/s rational root and s divides an, r divides a0?

Comment: @HyperGroups http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: @HyperGroups See the above link; it's the second one (the "other about r/s ...") you mention.

Comment: @Kaish xixi, thank you, do you think my formula in the post is interesting? <kbd>tag

Comment: @CalvinLin Well, I am not sure, because I found this excersise from my old notebooks, I have no context either.

Comment: Well,,,Thomas edited my <kbd> tag

Comment: I'm not sure if rational roots work immediately/quickly (and if it does I'd like to see how). Was about to comment on Goos' solution but he deleted it.

Comment: The <kbd> tag is a specification of font, specifically calling for a fixed width font. But the dollar-sign tags for LaTeX interfere with the fixed-width criterion. <kbd> should hardly ever be used on M.SE, because it is about spacing and alignment, but we have LaTeX for that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok, I'll take that suggestion, I just use it for fun because it seems like one frame around the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by $n!$ we can make all coefficients to become integers. By the rational root theorem, the root has to be integer and divides $n!.$ Moreover, since all coefficients except for the first one are divisible by $n,$ $x^n$ is divisible by $n.$ Take any prime divisor $p$ of $n.$ Then $p$ divides $x$ and it is enough to show that $x^k\frac{n!}{k!}$ is divisible by the higher power of $p$ than $n!$ for each $1\le k\le n$ The power of $p$ that $k!$ is divisible is less than $k/p+k/p^2+...=\frac{k}{p-1}\le k$ provided $p\ge 2$ and the result follows.

Comment: +1 I think this is a great solution, and deserves more up votes.